# The derivative of Frobenius norm with respect to the transpose of the matrix

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

The F-norm is $\|X-T^{\top}Z\|_F^2$,my question is what's the derivative with respect to $T$?

My solution is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|X-T^{\top}Z\|_F^2 &= {\rm tr}\Big(\big(X-T^{\top}Z\big)^{\top}\big(X-T^{\top}Z\big)\Big)\\
&={\rm tr}\Big(X^{\top}X-X^{\top}T^{\top}Z-Z^{T}TX+Z^{\top}TT^{\top}Z\Big)
\end{aligned}
$$
So differentiate with respect to $T$ is
$$
2ZZ^{\top}T-2ZX^{\top}=2Z\big(Z^{\top}T-X^{\top}\big)=2Z\big(T^{\top}Z-X\big)^{\top}
$$
But the answer is
$$
2\big(T^{\top}Z-X\big)Z
$$
Is the answer right?If so,can you give me a solution,thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the dimensions of $X$, $T$, and $Z$?

Comment: Anyway, I think your answer looks correct to me

Comment: @user550103 I think the dimension don't influence the result and I omit here for simplicity,thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Frobenius norm is unaffected by negation or transposition, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\,\big\|A\big\|_F^2}
\def\G{\frac{\partial \p}{\partial T}}
\p &= {\rm Tr}(A^TA) &\equiv A:A \\
\big\|-\!A\big\|_F^2 &= (-\!A):(-\!A) &= A:A \\
\big\|A^T\big\|_F^2 &= {\rm Tr}(AA^T) &= A:A   
\qquad\qquad\qquad \\
}$$
Substituting $\,A=(Z^TT-X^T)\:$ yields the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
dA &= Z^TdT \\
d\p &= 2A:dA = 2A:Z^TdT = 2ZA:dT \\
\G &= 2ZA = 2Z(Z^TT-X^T) \\
}$$
So your calculation is correct.

However, some [layout conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) insist that this result should be transposed
$$\eqalign{
\G &= 2\,(T^TZ-X)Z^T
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\\
}$$